# Python equivalent for a C expression

Tags: python, c, expression

Dear fellow C programmers, sorry to ask such a basic question to you, but what would be the equivalent of this:

```
val = dim == 0 ? 1 : S(dim) * pow(radius * 0.5, dim) / dim
```

in Python? I am wrapping some C code and I need to know what is going on in this line in order to compare with the Python results...

Comment: Should't this be addressed "Dear fellow **Python** programmers" ? (I know plenty C programmers, including myself, that know zilch about python).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary conditional operator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Python Conditional Expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

From Python 2.5 onwards, the conditional expression - `a ? b : c` can be written like this:

```
b if a else c
```

So, your expression will be equivalent to:

```
val = 1 if dim == 0 else S(dim) * pow(radius * 0.5, dim) / dim
```

Comment: as we would say here "gut gemacht!" ;)

Comment: @SaulloCastro means??

Comment: Gut Gemacht Rohit! :)

Answer (score 1):

For most languages, including Python(without braces(?) and correct indentation), the following C statement:

```
val = (dim == 0) ? 1 : S(dim) * pow(radius * 0.5, dim) / dim;
```

can be written as something like: (minor differences are language specific, etc.)

```
if (dim == 0)
   {
      val = 1;
   } else {
      val = S(dim) * pow(radius * 0.5, dim) / dim;
   }
```

However, the Python code given in a previous answer is **very** nice!

Comment: thank you to show how the compact expression would look like in an `if-else` statement in `C`...

Comment: @SaulloCastro, not a problem.  Overtime you might come to like the "conditional expression" for quick one line data entry.